# How to filter specific paths in neo4j?

Tags: neo4j

I have a graph db that maps out the relations between source files. I have the following query which finds all files that are calling the methods defined in the given source file.

```
MATCH (sourceFile:JSSourceFile {filename: 'test.js'})-[:Defines]->(sourceMethod:Method)
<-[:Calls*1..5]-
(callerMethod:Method)<-[:Defines]-(callerFile:TSSourceFile)
RETURN sourceFile.fileName AS sourceFile, COLLECT(DISTINCT callerFile.fileName) AS callerFile
ORDER BY sourceFile
```

Now I have added another label `Utility` to some of the existing `JSSourceFile` nodes. I need to filter out the `TSSourceFile` whose methods calls the `utilityMethods`. Doing this to avoid the utility method calls which in turn being called by the TSSoureFiles and end up polluting the results

```
(:JSSourceFile)-[:Defines]-(sourceMethods:Methods)<-[:Calls*1..5]-(:Method)<-[:Defines]-(callerMethod:TSSourceFile)
(:JSSourceFile:Utility)-[:Defines]->(utilityMethods:Method)
Need to eliminate this relationship: 
(sourceMethods)-[:Calls]->(utilityMethods)<-[:Calls]-(callerMethod)
```

I have tried the following queries but they are running forever on depth 2+ and I need depth in range of 1..5.

```
MATCH (:JSSourceFile:Utility)-[:Defines]->(utilityMethods:Method)
WITH DISTINCT (:TSSourceFile)-[:Defines]->(:Method)-[:Calls]->(utilityMethods) AS utilityCallerFile
MATCH
results=((sourceFile:JSSourceFile {fileName:"test.js"})-[:Defines]->(:Method)
<-[:Calls]-
(callerSub:Method)<-[:Defines]-(callerFile:TSSourceFile))
WITH DISTINCT [result IN nodes(results) WHERE "TSSourceFile" IN labels(result)] as results, sourceFile.fileName AS sourceFile, utilityCallerFile AS utilityCallerFile
RETURN sourceFile, COLLECT(DISTINCT [result IN results WHERE NOT(result IN utilityCallerFile) | result.fileName]) AS callerFile
ORDER BY sourceFile
```

```
MATCH
(sourceFile:JSSourceFile {fileName:"test.js"})-[:Defines]->(:Method)
<-[:Calls*1..3]-
(callerMethod:Method)<-[:Defines]-(callerFile:TSSourceFile)
WHERE NOT EXISTS((callerMethod)-[:Calls]->(sourceFile:Utility))
RETURN sourceFile.fileName, collect(DISTINCT callerFile.fileName)
```

I'm a beginner in neo4j and any guidance would be really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I feel I may be oversimplifying your problem but if just want to exclude the `:JSSourceFile` nodes that also have the `:Utility` label then I believe this modification of your first query will work:

```
MATCH (sourceFile:JSSourceFile)-[:Defines]->(sourceMethod:Method)<-[:Calls*1..5]-(callerMethod:Method)<-[:Defines]-(callerFile:TSSourceFile)
WHERE NOT sourceFile:Utility
RETURN sourceFile.fileName AS sourceFile, COLLECT(DISTINCT callerFile.fileName) AS callerFile
ORDER BY sourceFile
```

I added the `WHERE NOT` clause to strip out the :Utility nodes.

Comment: Hi @hoyski, thanks for reaching out. What I'm trying to achieve is to eliminate the paths where the utility methods lies between the sourceMethod and callerMethod. Something like sourceMethod-[:Calls]->(utilityMethod)<-[:Calls]-(callerMethod).

Comment: Sorry @hoyski for being unclear, I updated the question too

Comment: Do the last two MATCH statements both return the correct results? They're just too slow?

Comment: Both the original query and the 1st query gives the same results on lower depth. I'll only know if the query returns right results on higher depth but its too slow to return the results